# What is a good example of implementing old-school design in a 4e module?

Tags: dnd-4e, osr, published-adventures

I've done some poking around and haven't found anything.  It looks like the RPGA "Village of Hommlet" drew on its heritage a bit, but I'm pretty sure I won't be able to get my hands on that.  I also know (vaguely) the OGL limits who can put out modules, but I thought I'd see if anyone has seen anything.

*EDIT*: Per the request in the comment, I'm clarifying that I'm not looking something that meets a specific set of old-school criteria, just anything that people feel is in line with some of the design philosophy trends of earlier games.

Comment: What aspects of old-school are you looking for?

Comment: Anything, really: megadungeon, sandbox elements, dungeons with lots of empty rooms, cursed items, modules that emphasize player skill, modules that don't emphasize a specific linear plot, etc.  Any or all of these.  There are certain tropes that tend to be more common in older games, and I'm curious to see how people have implemented them for 4e.

Comment: If you don't find any we should write some.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Goodman Games](http://www.goodman-games.com/dcc-modules4e.html) are doing 4e stuff, continuing on from their line of 3e classic style adventures.

Just check out the look and feel of this cover!

[image]

At the time of writing there's 17 modules on their 4e section, they were very prolific with their 3e stuff, publishing somewhere around 60 modules.

Comment: Hmm...certainly the *cover* nails the old school look and feel.

Comment: This definitely looks promising--glancing over the reviews, it seems that the design ideas vary from module to module, but there as Beska says, C9 definitely has the cover down.  I will be working through these for ideas.

Answer (score 0):

WotC reprinted Tomb of Horrors for 4th ed and it does an excellent job of re-capturing the flavor of the original.  Besides, if you players ever played the original, it will be fun to watch them cry when you announce ToH for your 4th ed game.

Comment: There was also an RPGA rewards 4e Conversion of the original Tomb of Horrors